# MongoError: cannot infer query fields to set, path 'users' is matched twice

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, upsert

I am using mongoose. I want to create a document `chat` with an array `users` (including `userId1`, `userId2`), if I do not find it:

This is how I do:

```
ChatModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { users: { $all: [userId1, userId2] }},
  { $setOnInsert: {
    users: [userId1, userId2]
  }},
  { upsert: true })
  .exec()
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

But I got the error:

> MongoError: cannot infer query fields to set, path 'users' is matched
>   twice

This is `Chat` Schema:

```
{
  users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}
```

How can I do it correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this as the condition

```
{
  "users": {
        $all: [
          {"$elemMatch": userId1},
          {"$elemMatch": userId2}
        ]
  }......
}
```

Comment: This results in a  _$elemMatch needs an Object_ error.
It can be solved by using the `$eq` operator 
Like  `{$elemMatch: {$eq: userId1}},`

Answer (score 1):

I know this already has an answer but to hopefully save someone else some time, I had to do this:

```
{
  "users": {
        $all: [
          { $elemMatch: { $eq: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId1) }},
          { $elemMatch: { $eq: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId2) }}
        ]
  }......
}
```

### Modifications from accepted answer:

- The $eq was needed just like Dave Howson said in his comment on the accepted answer.
- mongoose.Types.ObjectId was needed because I guess the _id property on my schema instance was a string.

Comment: adding `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this issue:

```
db.foo.update({a:{$all:[{$elemMatch:{$eq:0}},{$elemMatch:{$eq:1}}]}},{$set:{b:1}},{upsert:true})
```

This will match when `a` is an array with both 0 and 1 in it and it will upsert otherwise.

From: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13843?focusedCommentId=2305903&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-2305903