# Mongoose: cannot infer query fields to set, path 'participants' is matched twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose with Node.js to create a document of `chat` with `participants` as one of the fields if the chat doesn't exist.

If it does exist then simply increment the status to 1 or any number.

My current Solution:

```
 try {

   let query = { participants: { $all: [CURRENT_USER_ID, TARGETED_ID] } };
   let update = { $inc: { status: 1 }};
   let options = { upsert: true, new: true };
   let chat = await Chat.findOneAndUpdate(
      query,
      update,
      options
   ).exec();
   console.log(chat);

  } catch (err) {

    console.log(err.message);

  }
```

I will receive an error

> "cannot infer query fields to set, path 'participants' is matched
>   twice"

I even use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060861/mongoerror-cannot-infer-query-fields-to-set-path-users-is-matched-twice) and it doesn't work, it created an empty list of participants instead.

```
let query = {
       participants: {
         $all: [
           { $elemMatch: { $eq: CURRENT_USER_ID } },
           { $elemMatch: { $eq: TARGETED_ID } }
         ]
       }
     };
```

Any help would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: I would get `cannot infer query fields to set, path 'participants' is matched twice`

Comment: I posted another question similar to what Im facing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993470/mongoose-cannot-infer-query-fields-to-set-path-participants-is-matched-twice if you could solve these two, it would be really helpful. Thanks